# Family Wise Error Rate controlled by method of maximum statistics

Tags: r, statistics

I am flipping each coin 100 times in a bag of 50 coins and then I want to use the Method of Maximum statistics in order to determine the Family Wise Error Rate. However, I keep getting an FWER of 1 which feels wrong.

```
  coins <- rbinom(50, 100, 0.5)
```

So I start by defining a new function where we input how many times we do randomizations, the coins themselves, and how many times we flip them.

```
simulate_max <- function(n_number_of_randomizations, input_coins, N_number_of_tosses, alpha = 0.05) {

  maxList <- NULL
```

Then we do a for loop for every time we have specified.

```
  for (iteration in 1:n_number_of_randomizations){
```

Now we shuffle the list of coins

```
  CoinIteration <- sample(input_coins)
```

Now we apply the binary test to every coin in the bag

```
testresults <- map_df(CoinIteration, function(x) tidy(binom.test(x,N_number_of_tosses,p=alpha)) )
```

Now we want to add the maximum result from every test to the max list.

```
  thisRandMax <- max(testresults$statistic)
  maxList <- c(maxList, thisRandMax)
```

}

Finally, we iterate through every member of the maximum list to subtract the expected value of heads (ie 50 for 50% chance * 100 tosses.

```
  for (iterator2 in 1:length(maxList)){

maxList[iterator2]<-maxList[iterator2]-(0.5*N_number_of_tosses)  
  
  }
```

Return the output from the function

```
return(data.frame(maxList))
}
```

Now we apply this simulation for each of the requested iterations.

```
repsmax = map_df(1:Nreps, ~simulate_max(Nrandomizations,coins,Ntosses))
```

Now we calculate the fwer by dividing the increased amount by the total number of cells.

```
fwer = sum(repsmax>0) / (Nreps*Nrandomizations)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of Family Wise Error Rate. What does `coins` represent?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for taking a look coins is the list of coins which have been flipped and how many times it is heads, eg for 100 tosses with fair coins it will look like [50, 53, 48, 52...]

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Also some constants are not defined in the post like `Nrandomizations`, `Nreps` and `Ntosses`.

Comment: Nrandomizations
Nreps 
Ntosses 
Are each just numbers.

For example, 5 randomisations, 100 reps and 100 tosses.

Comment: I am trying to answer this question: https://gyazo.com/d158ecbc62722b7f4aad8cc610136b1b

Comment: what is the `estimate` column of cointests dataframe mentioned in the question above?

Comment: estimate is the estimated percentage of heads for that coin. Eg 0.45 when the coins actual value chance of heads is 0.5

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to get people working on this problem if you can make your example reproducible, so that they can copy the code from your question, paste it into an R script, and run it. Right now it's difficult to figure out the structure of the code and some of the objects are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues that I think would be good to clarify.

A `FWER of ~1` seems about right to me given the parameters of your experiment. `FWER` relates to Type I error, and for a single normally distributed test at `alpha = 0.05`, `FWER = 1 - P(Type I error = 0);` `FWER = 1 - 0.95 = 0.05`. For two tests at `alpha = 0.05, FWER = 1 - P(Type I error = 0); FWER = 1 - 0.95^2 = 0.0975`. You have 50 coins (50 tests), so your `FWER` at `alpha = 0.05` is `1 - 0.95^50 = 0.923`. If your code treats the 100 coins as 100 tests, your `FWER` will be = `0.996 (~1)`.

You can control for Type I error (account for multiple testing) by using e.g. the Bonferroni correction (alpha / n). If you change your alpha to `"0.05 / 50" = 0.001`, you will control your `FWER` (reduce it) to `0.05 (1 - 0.999^50 = ~0.049)`. I suspect this is the answer you are looking for: `if alpha = 0.001 then FWER = 0.05` and you have an acceptable chance of incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis.

I don't know what the "maximum estimate of the effect size" is, or how to calculate it, but given that the two distributions are approximately identical, the effect size will be ~ 0. It then makes sense that controlling `FWER` to 0.05 (by adjusting alpha to 0.001) is the 'answer' to the question and if you can get your code to reflect that logic, I think you'll have your solution.